# AchartEngine Android Special Pie Chart

Tags: android, achartengine, pie-chart

I'm using the AchartEngine libraries to make a pie chart app. But I want to display two dimensional data like this [image: Special Pie:]

I can get nice standard pie charts but I know how to do the second dimension. Can anyone please help? The guys on the achartengine-google-support group say it's possible but I was redirected here for tech questions.

Many Thanks

Comment: sorry "..but I know how to do the second dimension..." should read I don't know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the Budget Pie chart demo it shows you how to highlight a section of your pie chart (https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/BudgetPieChart.java). Take a look at "Project 1" below to see how this looks.

[image: pie chart]

However there is no way to change the radius like you want to in your screenshot above. If you want to achieve this the easiest way would be to extend PieChart and copy over the draw method. In the draw method where it renders highlighted sections (if (seriesRenderer.isHighlighted()) ...) use a different radius instead of translating to an offset.